# Don't understand conversion from integer to smaller pointer error

Tags: c, iar, 8051

I am working on an 8051 platform which has a 16 bit pointer width.

I have a common code module for handling flash emulation and there's a function that returns the 16 bit start address of a page:

```
volatile u16_t start_address = find_start_address_of_page( page );
```

I think want to pass this 'address' to a CRC function that wants a ***u8_t**** as a parameter so I cast it in the function call like so:

```
(u8_t *)start_address
```

This generates the warning

> Warning[Pe1053]: conversion from integer to smaller pointer

Which confuses me a bit, because a ***u8_t**** is 16 bits wide, and my variable is a 16 bit variable.. Is it simply that the compiler is warning about an "integer to pointer" conversion in general?

The code works fine, I just want to be sure I'm not missing something silly here...

Comment: start_address is a integer with 16 bits, not a pointer to an integer.

Try using (u8_t *)(&start_address)

Comment: Yeah but thats not what I want to achieve - that would give me the _address_ of start_address. start_address is the address value itself, stored as an integer.

Comment: I see. Your logic is correct for your program. But the compiler is expecting a variable that is a pointer not a integer value that has   the address. That's why the warning is happening. The cast is done and working as you want but there are cases that this don't happen and that's the reason why the compiler gives you this warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write that your 8051 platform has a 16 bit pointer width.

As far as I know, the 8051 has different address ranges for
 - the internal RAM in the processor (max 256 Byte) 
 - external RAM (max 64k)
 - Program Memory (max 64k)

The compiler I have worked with (Keil) therefore had at least four different pointer types.
  An 8 bit wide 'data' pointer for the internal RAM.
  A 16 bit wide 'xdata' pointer for the external RAM.
  A 16 bit wide 'code' pointer for the Program Memory.
  A 24 bit wide universal pointer which could be set to point to any of the three memory types. The first byte was used to select the memory type.

The warning text could mean that the compiler wants to convert your 16 bit value to an address in internal RAM which is only 8 bits wide.

Comment: Excellent point - I never thought of that. I'll revisit this with that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to silence your warning you could use a union to move your information into a different type, i.e.

```
union {
   u16_t origType;
   u8_t *newtype;
} u;

u.origType = start_address;
```

Assuming they are the same size you can then pass `u.newtype` into you function.

Comment: Cheers - sadly MISRA doesn't allow unions!

Its ok though, am happy to suppress the warning, I just was making sure my thinking was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since `start_address` is a variable that holds a memory address, you should declare and use it as such, meaning a pointer:

```
volatile u16_t *start_address = find_start_address_of_page( page );
```

Of course this also means that your function `find_start_address_of_page();` has to return a pointer.

By the way, the fact that `int` and `int *` are both 16 bits wide (on your processor) is not enough. For example, a pointer to an int on most (all?) 16 bit processors has to be aligned to an even (multiple of 2) address, because of limitations of the assembler instructions and/or the data bus implementation.

In the same way, things like `start_address++;` increments differently depending if it is an `int` or an `int *` (or even a `char *`). If it is an `int` (or a `char *`) it will increment by one, but if it is an `int *` it will increment by two.

By this I'm trying to show that the compiler makes a lot of checks beyond the number of bits, depending on the type of variable (and the processor abilities).

Answer (score -3):

start_address is of type u16_t, and not a pointer.

if you want to pass his address to CRC, then try this:

```
((u8_t *)((u16_t *)start_address))
```

Comment: As the name of the variable implies, `start_address` contains the address itself.

Comment: in this case try this, ((u8_t *)((u16_t *)start_address))